# CMOS: dual of cascode circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier

If this is a differential folded cascode CMOS amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0PDCO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(where the "first" stage is nMOS and the "second" one is pMOS), can the following be considered as its dual?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAy9sU.png)</sup>

It doesn't matter the different DC sources disposition and their values. My question is: is the second circuit built following the same cascode principle of the first one?

Comment: My problem with this question is that the top circuit doesn't look like a cascode circuit. Please justify that the 1st circuit is a cascode amplifier.

Comment: Can we assume that this is an IC design, and that the substrate connection on each transistor is NOT connected to its source? Otherwise, you have a lot of parasitic "body" diodes that prevent the circuit from working as intended.

Comment: It's a folded cascode amplifier.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the circuit was wrong; now I corrected the schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka It is a folded cascode CMOS amplifier, as stated by HKOB.

Comment: @HKOB but the circuit was drawn incorrectly so how could you say that?

Comment: @DaveTweed In the cascode transistor (M3, M4 for the first circuit) the bulk is connected to Vdd. The schematic editor has only that symbol for the pMOS, where the body seems connected to the source, but in this case it isn't. So, if the body was connected to the source it wouldn't work correctly?

Comment: @Andyaka I recognized the topology, but didn't spot the misplaced Vout in the first circuit. The second circuit had Vout in a sensible place from the start, or 23 hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except for the location of the output connection (the first circuit looks wrong), the two circuits are topologically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I consider to be a differential cascode amplifer: -

[image]

Note the important difference - the output is taken from the drains of the upper transistors. What you appear to have is Vout taken from the drain of the 1st pair of transistors but this voltage will tend to be clamped by the sources of the 2nd pair.

Comment: Thats a cascode circuit; the OP's circuit is a *folded* cascode cirucit (when working properly !)

Comment: @jp314 you are absolutely correct but, if you go and look at the edits performed on the question you will see that he originally called it a "plain" cascode circuit and had the output in the wrong place. This of course makes my answer look stupid so here I am justifying that it's not a stupid answer and that the guy raising the question altered it after I made my answer.